Error while using cosine function to estimate Margins for tikzpicture of Bohr's model of carbon atom in blank circular space within \lipsum[1-4] text
After many attempts, still experiencing a persistent error, as exemplified with the following MWE:
(See Draw Bohr atomic model with electron shells in TeX?)

% Insert Bohr’s Model of Carbon atom inside blank circle within the \lipsum[1-4] text.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{contour}
% \usepackage{shapepar}
\usepackage{cutwin}

\newtoks\Margins
\Margins={}

\foreach \angle in {0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90} {%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\width}{0.4 * cos(\angle)}%
\Margins=\expandafter{\the\Margins\width\textwidth, \width\textwidth,}%
}%
\foreach \angle in {90, 85, 80, 75, 70, 65, 60, 55, 50, 45, 40, 35, 30, 25, 20, 15, 10, 5, 0} {%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\width}{0.4 * cos(\angle)}%
\Margins=\expandafter{\the\Margins\width\textwidth, \width\textwidth,}%
}%
% \edef\tempmargin{\the\Margins\relax}  % Errors out
\xdef\tempmargin{\the\Margins\relax}

\typeout{Margins: \the\Margins}
\show\tempmargin

\def\proton(#1,#2){%
  \shade [ball color=myyellow] (#1,#2) circle (10pt);
  \node at (#1,#2) {\texttt{+}};
}
\def\neutron(#1,#2){%
  \shade [ball color=myorange] (#1,#2) circle (10pt);
}
\def\electron{%
  \shade [ball color=gray!30] (0,0) circle (5pt);
  \node at (0,0) {\texttt{-}};
}
\def\sorbit(#1,#2){%
  \draw[
  color=violet,
  rotate=#1,
  postaction=decorate,
  decoration={markings,
  mark=at position #2 with {\electron},
  }]
  (0,0) ellipse (1.5 and 3.5);
}
\def\porbit(#1,#2){%
  \draw[
  color=violet,
  rotate=#1,
  postaction=decorate,
  decoration={markings,
  mark=at position #2 with {\electron},
  }]
  (0,0) ellipse (4 and 6);
}

\renewcommand\putstuffinpic{%
  \rput(0,-5\normalbaselineskip){%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]
      %%Nucleons
      \neutron(0.8,0.2)
      \proton(0.5,-0.5)
      \neutron(-0.25,-0.5)
      \neutron(0.55,0.8)
      \proton(-0.5,0.2)
      \proton(-0.1,0.8)
      \proton(0.5,0)
      \proton(0.12,0.6)
      \proton(0.12,-0.6)
      \neutron(-0.25,0)
      \neutron(-0.5,0.6)
      \neutron(0.5,-0.3)
      %%orbits
      \porbit(-20,.15)
      \porbit(15,.45)
      \sorbit(40,.9)
      \porbit(65,.6)
      \sorbit(100,.3)
      \porbit(125,.75)
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\expandafter\begin{shapedcutout}{2}{36}{\tempmargin}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{shapedcutout}
\end{document}

Appears the error is with the code to create the Margins clist, which is not functioning like it needs to for the shapedcutout environment, e.g.:
\newcommand\Margins{%
0.4\textwidth, 0.4\textwidth, 
0.38\textwidth, 0.38\textwidth,
0.36\textwidth, 0.36\textwidth,
0.34\textwidth, 0.34\textwidth,
0.32\textwidth, 0.32\textwidth,
0.30\textwidth, 0.30\textwidth,
0.28\textwidth, 0.28\textwidth,
0.26\textwidth, 0.26\textwidth,
0.24\textwidth, 0.24\textwidth,
0.22\textwidth, 0.22\textwidth,
0.20\textwidth, 0.20\textwidth,
0.20\textwidth, 0.20\textwidth,
0.20\textwidth, 0.20\textwidth,
0.20\textwidth, 0.20\textwidth,
0.22\textwidth, 0.22\textwidth,
0.24\textwidth, 0.24\textwidth,
0.26\textwidth, 0.26\textwidth,
0.28\textwidth, 0.28\textwidth,
0.30\textwidth, 0.30\textwidth,
0.32\textwidth, 0.32\textwidth,
0.34\textwidth, 0.34\textwidth,
0.36\textwidth, 0.36\textwidth,
0.38\textwidth, 0.38\textwidth,
0.4\textwidth, 0.4\textwidth
}


Your example does not work, because of undefined \putstuffinpic, so you cannot re-define it. Environment shapecutout is also undefined. However note, \foreach spans a group. So you need at least \global. But IMHO you don't want to add \width\textwidth to each, but the expansion of \width + \textwidth. I would recommend to do this using l3. There you can easily expand the argument before adding it to a token list. Or use a macro and \xdef instead of a token.

@cabohah My apologies … I’ve been working with both the shapepar and the cutwin packages and grabbed the wrong one (of the two that were open at the time) when I was constructing the MWE. The MWE is part of a much larger project. Both the \putstuffinpic command and the shapedcutout environment are defined in the cutwin package, NOT the shapepar package. I’ve changed the above code accordingly. Now it runs showing the error message that has dogged me. Apologies tor those who scratched their heads wondering what I was trying to do.

What exactly is the error message that you get? Can you add that to the question as well?

There are still undefined commands, colors etc. in your example. See my answer.

@RosesBouquet it is better to post your Update part as a second (self-)answer to this question. On the site we try to maintain a separation between questions and answers, so both of them can be found more easily and also independently voted on.

@Marijn
Thank you for the clarification. I wasn’t looking for any votes or credit. This was a Hail Mary for me. W/o cabohah’s code, I could not have performed any iterative testing to arrive at my final solution. That said, should I revise my Update as per your suggestion?

@RosesBouquet, it would be good to move the solution to a real answer. The votes are only one part of it, we try to keep questions and answers separate for future visitors to be able to determine quickly if their issue is similar and where they should look for the solution.

@Marijn
Done - Thank you.

As already told in comments, there are several more issues with your code. But there are two main issues:

Your usage of token register \Margins is wrong, because you always add the tokens \width\textwidth, \width\textwidth to \Margins. But you want \width to be expanded. And you add a comma at the end, that you don't want.
\foreach uses a group for the content. So after the loop \Margins would be empty again.

These two issues can be fixed using a macro instead of a token register and \xdef for extending the macro.
The other issues are undefined colors, undefined \rput, missing TikZ library etc. Instead of \rput I've simply used a \raisebox. Alternatively you could change the baseline and/or bounding box of the TikZ image.
One more issue is, that you cannot use \lipsum inside shadedcutout. \lipsum is defined \protected. But shadedcutout needs to expand the content. So I've used \blindtext instead, because it us not protected. And I've corrected the number of shape lines in the shadedcutout environment by simply counting them.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{contour}
% \usepackage{shapepar}
\usepackage{cutwin}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings} 

\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{254,241,24}
\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{234,125,1}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\Margins{\@gobble}
\makeatother

\newcounter{shapelines}

\foreach \angle in {0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90} {%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\width}{0.4 * cos(\angle)}%
  \xdef\Margins{\Margins,\width\textwidth, \width\textwidth}%
  \stepcounter{shapelines}%
}%
\foreach \angle in {90, 85, 80, 75, 70, 65, 60, 55, 50, 45, 40, 35, 30, 25, 20, 15, 10, 5, 0} {%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\width}{0.4 * cos(\angle)}%
  \xdef\Margins{\Margins,\width\textwidth, \width\textwidth}%
  \stepcounter{shapelines}%
}%

\typeout{Margins: \detokenize\expandafter{\Margins}}
%\show\Margins

\def\proton(#1,#2){%
  \shade [ball color=myyellow] (#1,#2) circle (10pt);
  \node at (#1,#2) {\texttt{+}};
}
\def\neutron(#1,#2){%
  \shade [ball color=myorange] (#1,#2) circle (10pt);
}
\def\electron{%
  \shade [ball color=gray!30] (0,0) circle (5pt);
  \node at (0,0) {\texttt{-}};
}
\def\sorbit(#1,#2){%
  \draw[
  color=violet,
  rotate=#1,
  postaction=decorate,
  decoration={markings,
  mark=at position #2 with {\electron},
  }]
  (0,0) ellipse (1.5 and 3.5);
}
\def\porbit(#1,#2){%
  \draw[
  color=violet,
  rotate=#1,
  postaction=decorate,
  decoration={markings,
  mark=at position #2 with {\electron},
  }]
  (0,0) ellipse (4 and 6);
}

\renewcommand\putstuffinpic{%
\raisebox{-12\baselineskip}{%
  \kern-5em\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.25]
      %%Nucleons
      \neutron(0.8,0.2)
      \proton(0.5,-0.5)
      \neutron(-0.25,-0.5)
      \neutron(0.55,0.8)
      \proton(-0.5,0.2)
      \proton(-0.1,0.8)
      \proton(0.5,0)
      \proton(0.12,0.6)
      \proton(0.12,-0.6)
      \neutron(-0.25,0)
      \neutron(-0.5,0.6)
      \neutron(0.5,-0.3)
      %%orbits
      \porbit(-20,.15)
      \porbit(15,.45)
      \sorbit(40,.9)
      \porbit(65,.6)
      \sorbit(100,.3)
      \porbit(125,.75)
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{shapedcutout}{2}{\value{shapelines}}{\Margins}
\blindtext
\end{shapedcutout}
\end{document}


Please next time be more careful with your example code. Too many mistakes away from the actual problem can prevent someone from looking further into the issue.

This is an answer using cabohah’s answer that allowed me to perform iterative testing to arrive at my final solution.
The other answer enabled me to refine the code to get as close to what I was looking for as possible (a circular text void surrounding Bohr's model of the carbon atom).
After a few iterations, and realizing I also needed to replace the cosine function with the ( 1 - sine )
function to get the correct curvature around the Bohr carbon atom. I also introduced a few new adjustments to a few new coefficients that were needed to adjust the shape of the shapedcutout environment for a true circular void within the \lipsum1 text.
Here is my final code: (See below for the final image.)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{contour}
% \usepackage{shapepar}
\usepackage{cutwin}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings} 

\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{254,241,24}
\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{234,125,1}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\Margins{\@gobble}
\makeatother

\newcounter{shapelines}

% \foreach \angle in {0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90}
\foreach \angle in {0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90} {%
% \pgfmathsetmacro{\width}{0.4 * cos(\angle)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\width}{0.450 * (1-(0.6*sin(\angle)))}%
  \xdef\Margins{\Margins,\width\textwidth, \width\textwidth}%
  \stepcounter{shapelines}%
}%
% \foreach \angle in {90, 85, 80, 75, 70, 65, 60, 55, 50, 45, 40, 35, 30, 25, 20, 15, 10, 5, 0}
 \foreach \angle in {90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0} {%
% \pgfmathsetmacro{\width}{0.4 * cos(\angle)}%
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\width}{0.450 * (1-(0.6*sin(\angle)))}%
  \xdef\Margins{\Margins,\width\textwidth, \width\textwidth}%
  \stepcounter{shapelines}%
}%

\typeout{Margins: \detokenize\expandafter{\Margins}}
%\show\Margins

\def\proton(#1,#2){%
  \shade [ball color=myyellow] (#1,#2) circle (10pt);
  \node at (#1,#2) {\texttt{+}};
}
\def\neutron(#1,#2){%
  \shade [ball color=myorange] (#1,#2) circle (10pt);
}
\def\electron{%
  \shade [ball color=gray!30] (0,0) circle (5pt);
  \node at (0,0) {\texttt{-}};
}
\def\sorbit(#1,#2){%
  \draw[
  color=violet,
  rotate=#1,
  postaction=decorate,
  decoration={markings,
  mark=at position #2 with {\electron},
  }]
  (0,0) ellipse (1.5 and 3.5);
}
\def\porbit(#1,#2){%
  \draw[
  color=violet,
  rotate=#1,
  postaction=decorate,
  decoration={markings,
  mark=at position #2 with {\electron},
  }]
  (0,0) ellipse (4 and 6);
}

\renewcommand\putstuffinpic{%
% \raisebox{-12\baselineskip}{%
\raisebox{-16.7\baselineskip}{%
%  \kern-5em\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.25]
  \kern-9.5em\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
      %%Nucleons
      \neutron(0.8,0.2)
      \proton(0.5,-0.5)
      \neutron(-0.25,-0.5)
      \neutron(0.55,0.8)
      \proton(-0.5,0.2)
      \proton(-0.1,0.8)
      \proton(0.5,0)
      \proton(0.12,0.6)
      \proton(0.12,-0.6)
      \neutron(-0.25,0)
      \neutron(-0.5,0.6)
      \neutron(0.5,-0.3)
      %%orbits
      \porbit(-20,.15)
      \porbit(15,.45)
      \sorbit(40,.9)
      \porbit(65,.6)
      \sorbit(100,.3)
      \porbit(125,.75)
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{shapedcutout}{2}{\value{shapelines}}{\Margins}
% \Blindtext
\lipsum[1]
\end{shapedcutout}
\end{document}

Here is the final image:


@daleif that's because I suggested it :) this is imo more of an answer than an update post, therefore it should be an answer. I have edited it a bit to remove the "forum-like" style.

@daleif and Marijn
I’m not an expert on SE protocol by any measure. Please make whatever changes are appropriate. Thank you. As I mentioned, this entire exercise was a stretch for me. My solution would not have happened w/o cabohah’s post.

@Marijn Excellent! Thanks!

@Marijn sorry about that
